# As a developer, how to display notifications on MacOS

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, applescript, notifications

I am trying to find out how to display a notification on a MacOS (macbook pro) machine.
I see this:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/DisplayNotifications.html

(Ideally there would be a Node.js binding to a C library which could allow me to display notifications without launching a child process which then calls apple scripts).

Having trouble finding this info on the google:

[image]

is there some API or C / Objective-C library that I can call to display a notification on a MacOS machine?

Comment: The official documentation is [available here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/).

Comment: this is for macbook not ios. I will make that clearer.

Comment: The info there applies to macOS, too

Comment: thanks, can you add an answer on how to do it? i will upvote it

Comment: What tools/languages are you using to write your app?

Comment: I am using Node.js - I can launch a child process to run an apple script, but in an ideal world, there would be a C library that I can call, and there would be C bindings I can use from Node.js.  It looks like there already are JS bindings, for example here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/DisplayNotifications.html

Comment: You should be able to use the [`node-notifier`](https://github.com/mikaelbr/node-notifier) package.

Comment: looks like node-notifier uses child procs, not C bindings to do the work, but I guess that's good enough, I could optimize things later

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Node.js and want to create notifications on multiple platforms including Apple, this library probably has what you want:

https://github.com/mikaelbr/node-notifier

disclaimer: I am not the author